# PHP/MySQL - Storing of dates for use with date selection reports across timezones

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

currently debating the best way to proceed with regard to storing dates and would appreciate experienced comments - looking for the 'why' rather than the 'how'.

**Scenario:**

We are developing a system that allows clients (across multiple timezones) to create transactional data. At sign-up the client will have nominated their timezone. A large part of the system revolves around the client running date and time related reports on the transactional data.

We have read numerous questions and comments regarding the best way to store the transactional date field and most say store as UTC and then perform various date and time related functions to work out the time in the various timezones in order to run the selection reports.

Our question is - why go to all the trouble of storing in UTC - what is the advantage of storing the date in UTC. From our point of view we have the client's nominated timezone so if we store the date/time in their correct timezone then it’s a calculation that we run once per transaction - thereafter all their reporting will work without any date transforming calculations.

As most of the questions and comments we have read refer to the 'How' we think there must be something about the 'Why' that we have missed.

So, in summary, before we make our decision have we missed something - is there an absolute 'must store dates as UTC' reason?

Thanks for reading - any comments appreciated.

Comment: Do the clients report on their own calculations only?

Comment: Each client can only ever access their own transactional data and there is no logical reason or statistical requirements to run reports on multi-client amalgamated data.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments – good debate Glavic. In the absence of an absolute reason to store the dates in UTC, as per our question, we would select Labib’s answer for his comment “in a controlled environment it's totally the same “.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, in my opinion there is no 'must' in this! this is totally a design issue, what you choose to use will determine the way the things will work, in either case, it's just a referencing issue, the people who are suggesting the use of UTC, is because it is the well known and verified reference, and no matter how big your program becomes or where your clients are, the reference is always there, but if you use, another time zone, things will work the same way but the time zone you choose will be the reference, which may cause misunderstanding in some situations, but still, in a controlled environment it's totally the same.
I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 1):

> Why go to all the trouble of storing in UTC?

There is no trouble of storing time in UTC. IMO it is easier to maintain datetime fields if they are all in same timezone, rather that every record of table being in different timezone and relation with `user` table tells you in what timezone that field is (or even absurd approach would be to store offset like `+02:00` in extra field).

> At sign-up the client will have nominated their timezone.

Think of what could happen when you will add functionalities:

- What if user changes there timezone?
- What if you will upgrade your system that user can give timezone for every request?
- etc.

> Is there an absolute 'must store dates as UTC' reason?

Ofc not; it is all about your design. What you choose is what you work with; just think what would be easier for you, for future upgrades, etc.

Comment: Glavic - thanks for your comment - just one point -> 'What if the user changes their timezone' - we consider this a reason for not storing time in UTC. With UTC format the changing of the timezone would change all historical transactional times and therefore destroy the integrity of the system. –

Comment: I disagree, but that depends on your project logic. If you have all user records saved in his timezone; and user changes his timezone, then you will need to update all his records, to fix his records to match his new timezone. On timezone change you must update records, which is not ok for a large datasets. I don't see that problem if you know that all records are in same offset.

Comment: "On timezone change you must update records" - we obviously live in different worlds - in mine 'System Integrity' is King - changing historical records opens up a minefield of business processing issues which could cost the company everything. Anyway, I think we are diverging from our main point. So lets just say that the client will not be changing timezones and shelve this discussion for another day. Thanks.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you will have timezone saved in (lets say) user table, like `+02:00`. And all his related records will be in his timezone, for example `... 08:00`. But if user changes his timezone (lets say it is possible) to `+03:00`, then all his already saved records are invalid, because `... +08:00` is now for timezone `+03:00` which is invalid; that way I said about update; and I agree, this is verry bad approach, and I never proposed this approach; my approach is, save all in one offset (best to be in UTC) and that is it.

Comment: "all his already saved records are invalid" - says who? As per your example :- Joe Blogs enters a transaction on the system at 8am every morning. Joe Blogs company moves east -> timezone changes by +1. As usual Joe Blogs gets to work at 8am every morning and enters a transaction on the system. But now Joe Blogs looks at historical transactions and sees that prior to the move he created them at 9am. In Joe Blogs world the system is wrong – he entered them at 8am.           In the real world you can never be so rigid as to force this type of change on a client - remember the customer is King :-)

Comment: _"and sees that prior to the move he created them at 9am. In Joe Blogs world the system is wrong"_ but in the world of time this is absolutely correct ;) but yes, I understood your logic. _"you can never be so rigid as to force this type of change on a client"_ but... client forced timezone change on him self ;))

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it would be best to store the dates/times as a unix value in the database. You then have an exact number that can easily be manipulated to be displayed however you like, using the stored timezone or otherwise, and crucially if you decided to change how its presented it would be quick to alter.